# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Amateur Radio Stack Exchange](http://ham.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ham.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [My neighbor is complaining about my transmissions, what can I do?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/my-neighbor-is-complaining-about-my-transmissions-what-can-i-do)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much should we invest time in collecting multipliers in the big contests?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-much-should-we-invest-time-in-collecting-multipliers-in-the-big-contests)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it safe to mount an active scanning antenna close to an hf antenna?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/909/is-it-safe-to-mount-an-active-scanning-antenna-close-to-an-hf-antenna)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I notify and publish information on experimental modes?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/996/how-do-i-notify-and-publish-information-on-experimental-modes)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can X-rays be used for communication?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/can-x-rays-be-used-for-communication)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are there ways for people with receivers to participate in contests?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/are-there-ways-for-people-with-receivers-to-participate-in-contests)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How would one automate HF communications to a specific location?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/how-would-one-automate-hf-communications-to-a-specific-location)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why do satellites receive and transmit on different bands?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/946/why-do-satellites-recieve-and-transmit-on-different-bands)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Optics for open-air visible spectrum communications](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/optics-for-open-air-visible-spectrum-communications)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How can I use all bands when I'm a guest on an Extra's station?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/how-can-i-use-all-bands-when-im-a-guest-on-an-extras-station)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---